# how to get the columns as a separate list datatype from a pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Below is in the type `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`   .

```
Priya                 10
test                   7
Satyam                 5
neha                   1
shivam                 1
pihu Investment        1
Name: Client_Name, dtype: int64
```

I wanted to extract these two as different list datatype in the same order.

```
names = ['Priya','test','Satyam','neha','shivam','pihu Investment']
count = [10,7,5,1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 2):

when your series is called `Client_Name`  try the following

```
names = list(Client_Name.index)
count = list(Client_Name.values)
```